# How to query table by relation table column condition

Tags: php, laravel

I have model Users

```
class Users extends Model implements  AuthenticatableContract
{
    use Authenticatable,HasApiTokens;

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    protected $fillable = ['email','password','email_token', 'verified'];

    public function user_info()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserInfo','user_id');
    }

}
```

In controller I want to query all users where relation table column "kind" equal to 1 .

```
So Users table has user_info_id(one to one) . User_info has kind_id.
```

I want query users by relation table column kind_id. 
I can do it by left join . But  How can I do it with relation?

I tried like this but it doesnt work

```
$univer_list = Users::with('user_info')->where('is_university',1)
            ->where('kind_id',1);
```

Comment: [Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)   enjoy

Comment: use `->get();` qith your query and check `dd($univer_list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` to query based on the existence of a relationship:

```
$univer_list = Users::where('is_university', 1)
    ->whereHas('user_info', function ($query) {
        $query->where('kind_id', 1);
    })->get();
```

Get only `Users`, which should be named `User`, that have a relationship with `UserInfo` where `kind_id` is equal to 1.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this condition in `with`

```
$univer_list = Users::with(['user_info' => function($q) {
                        $q->where('kind_id', 1);
                    }])->where('is_university', 1)->get();
```

I assumed that your `is_university` exists in `users` table and your `kind_id` column exists in `user_info` table.